# XPath to solve regex violation

Tags: c#, html, regex, xpath

Since the great comment and link to the great post [Never parse markup with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) by @kjhughes in my previous question [Regex repeat expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320902/regex-repeat-expression/49322209#49322209)
I have been changing as many unneeded regular expressions in my application which I used to remove content over writing a complete XPath.

But for the following I am wondering if there is also a way to solve it with XPath:

Data `Name: Herr FirstName LastName`

XPath so far: `//body//div/div/table/tr/td/div/table/tr[3]/td/div/table/tr/td/p[1]/span/text()`

Here I use following regex on: `(?<=Herr |Frau ).*`

This Because I only want the data `Firstname LastName` The reason I am asking for again a name is that this are two different mails I am scraping with different templates and want the application to be modular.

At the moment I do this still quite often in the application that I just remove all unwanted text with a regex, for this reason I want to know if it is also possible with XPath. This way I learn more about the XPath scraping and do not harm unholy childs :)

Comment: You may use regex or other string manipulation methods when you have *plain text*.

Comment: XPath and regex are not mutually exclusive. With XPath 2.0 (or greater), you can use regex expressions with `matches()`, `replace()`, `analyze-string()`, and `tokenize()`. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-matches

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net

Comment: Please make this question independent of your last question. That means you need to provide your sample data here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `text()` value of the XPath that you provided was "Name: Herr FirstName LastName"

Here is an example of how you can use regex in an XPath 2.0 statement to select the `text()` node if it contains "Herr" or "Frau" using [`matches()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-matches) (positive lookahead and negative lookbehind are not currently supported), and then use [`replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-replace) with a regex on that `text()` node value with a capture group to select the value "First Last"

```
//body//div/div/
  table/tr/td/div/
  table/tr[3]/td/div/
  table/tr/td/p[1]/
  span/text()[matches(., "Herr|Frau ")]/replace(.,'.*Herr|Frau (.*)', '$1')
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Wiktor Stribiżew comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322994/xpath-to-solve-regex-violation#comment85647503_49322994), you needn't avoid using regex on *plain text* from XML – it's *markup* which shouldn't be parsed via regex.

[Mads Hansen shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49324390/290085) how to use regex in XPath 2.0.

Here's a way to extract your targeted text if you only have XPath 1.0:

`substring(normalize-space(` ***your XPath here*** `), 12)`